# Inject a JavaScript API on everypage loaded on WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, scorm

I am coding a offline Scorm player, so need to inject an JavaScript API on every html page loaded by the WebView instance.
I tried to use a frame-set approach, but WebView doesnt behave the way it should (besides that, its deprecated in HTML5). 
How can I achieve this? I need the script to be injected before the page loads, because those html pages will consume the API on the body onLoad event..

When trying to to override the 'onPageStarted' WebViewClient method, although the event was fired, the JS code injected could not be reached.

Thanks in advance,
                Pablo

Comment: i too need solution for this.. please post the answer for this if you got solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can inject javascript everpageload by using below code, hope it helps

```
final WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
        /* JavaScript must be enabled if you want it to work, obviously */  
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  

        /* WebViewClient must be set BEFORE calling loadUrl! */  
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
            @Override  
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
            {  

                webview.loadUrl("javascript:myFunction()");  
            }  
        });  

        webview.loadUrl("http://code.google.com/android"); 

HTML 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
   alert("Hello World!");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the onLoad event of the body tag will consume the injected JS, so the script must be there

Comment: You can call the function from webview. you can look at the code, i edited it.